# Use of key as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

Is this phrase correct? *For teachers, updating becomes key*. 
Thanks

Comment: I think it's ok. Stylistically I'd prefer 'essential'. Or with the noun: 'a key task'.

Answer (score 1):

A valuable resource for an English learner is a **dictionary**. Paper ones are good, but are giving way to on-line ones. A good one is the Oxford Learner's Dictionary, which contains this entry:

> **key**
>
> adjective
>
> [usually before noun] most important; essential
>
> synonym critical, vital
>
> the key issue/factor/point
> He was a key figure in the campaign.
> She played a key role in the dispute.
> ‘Caution’ is the key word in this situation.
> Good communication is key to our success.
> His contribution could be key.

[Key (adjective)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/key_3)

Found by typing 'key adjective' into Google.